# How to read a specific XML node using php

Tags: php, xml

How can I read all int values from the xml below using php 5?

I'm trying to use simplexml_load_string but can't get the exact value.

My php code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo $xml->params[0]->param[0]->value[0]->array[0]->data[0]->value[0]->array[0]->data[0]->value[0]->int;
```

The XML

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value><array><data>
                <value><array><data>
                    <value><int>51838</int></value>
                    <value><double>57.83089533672552</double></value>
                </data></array></value>
                <value><array><data>
                    <value><int>20820</int></value>
                    <value><double>56.58239590002292</double></value>
                </data></array></value>
                <value><array><data>
                    <value><int>49286</int></value>
                    <value><double>55.950788550857176</double></value>
                </data></array></value>
                <value><array><data>
                    <value><int>51843</int></value>
                    <value><double>55.09419216830168</double></value>
                </data></array></value>
            </data></array></value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: Include your PHP code, since that's what you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not going to comment on the overly-deep nesting going on in your XML. I'll assume you have a reason for it.

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$valueList = $doc->xpath('/methodResponse/params/param/value/array/data/value');
while(list(, $node) = each($valueList)) {
    $intElement = $node->xpath('array/data/value/int');
    echo $intElement[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

will result in:

```
51838
20820
49286
51843
```

`$valueList` is assigned a list of all the `value` nodes. The second xpath query gets the `int` in each node. Do some reading on [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: Just for clarification: The reason for the "overly-deep nesting" is called XML-RPC (http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html). It might look overloaded, but that's how it was specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
$domObj= new DOMDocument(); 
$domObj->load("test.xml");
$value= $domObj->getElementsByTagName("value");
foreach( $value as $val) 
{ 

 $ints = $val->getElementsByTagName("int"); 
 $intVal  = $ints->item(0)->nodeValue; 

 echo "$intVal"; 
}
```